# Accessibility testing from external app to the app under test for iOS

Tags: ios, testing, accessibility, report, screenshot

Is there a library on iOS that, through its use on an app, allows you to have information on UI components (accessibility tests) of another application under test?

I have already tried with AXE by Deque, but Deque limits the use of the library only on the app under test and not through a secondary app used to test the app under test, I would like to create a secondary app which, through its use, I can test the accessibility of another app (app under test) by taking screenshots of various screens of this app and then send a report of the tests carried out.

Is there a library or a way to do this? Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with this

I have searched and tried various solutions, but these are parts of code or libraries that can only be integrated into the app under test, not into an external app that can then test a secondary app, such as AXE by Deque for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because iOS apps run in sandbox(like in a cage) and don't have access to another apps.

Comment: if instead I implemented the voice over service on an app and used the app with voice over to test another, is it possible to do something like this?